# Why will my opening menu not work in C++?

Tags: c++

At the moment I am compiling a program to do
1.  Prompt the user to enter a fixed number of MIDI notes for melody and bass

This is what the opening menu is for. However, the program will not proceed to prompt the user for the notes unless option '3' is pressed which as you can see is the EXIT option. I need to implement this piece of code to allow the user to enter a series of notes for 1. Melody and then 2. Bass. Why will it not take me to the validation if I press 1. or 2. but only when I press 3.?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
//********GET MIDI********//
string GetNote()
{
    string input;
    int loop = 1;
    cout << "Hello, please type in a note: "<< endl;
    cin >> input;
    while (1)
    {

        if (input.length() < 2 || input.length() > 3) //Step 1: If note name length is less than 2 OR more than 3, return false
        {
        cout<<"Note must be either 2 or 3 characters long!\n";
        cin >> input;
        }

        else if (((int)input[0] < 65)|| ((int)input[0] > 71 )) //Step 2: The note must be/(or be) between A and G
        {
        cout<<"The note must be between A to G!\n";
        cin >> input;
        }

        else if (input.length() == 2 && (isdigit(input[1]) == false))
            //(isdigit(note[GetValidNote()-1]) == false) //Step 3: If true, the last character must be a digit
        {
        cout<<"Last character must be a digit!\n";
        cin >> input;
        }
        else if (input.length() == 3 && (isdigit(input[2]) == false))
            //(isdigit(note[GetValidNote()-1]) == false) //Step 3: If true, the last character must be a digit
        {
        cout<<"Last character must be a digit!\n";
        cin >> input;
        }

         else if (input.length() == 3 && input[1] !='#') //Step 4: If note length is 3 note[1] (character 2) must be '#'.
        {
        cout<<"Invalid sharp note\n";
        cin >> input;
        }
        else
        {
            return input;
        }
    }

}

//********START UP MENU*******//


int StartUpMenu()
{
    while (1)
    {
        int choice;

        cout <<"::menu option::\n\n"
            <<"1. Bass\n"
            <<"2. Melody\n"
            <<"3. Exit\n"
            <<"Would you like to work with Bass or Melody first? Please enter 1 for Bass or 2 for Melody or 3 to Exit:";

        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 3) break;


        else if (choice == 1)
        {
            system ("CLS");
            cout<<"1. Bass \n\n";

            GetNote();

            system ("PAUSE");
            system ("CLS");


        }

        else if (choice == 2)
        {
             system ("CLS");
            cout<<"2. Melody \n\n";

            GetNote();

            system ("PAUSE");
            system ("CLS");
        }

        else if (choice > 3 || choice < 1)
        {
            system ("CLS");
            cout<<"2. Melody \n\n";
            system ("PAUSE");
            system ("CLS");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}


//********VALIDATION FOR NOTE NAME********//



int MidiStorage(string validnote)
{
    int MidiLetter = validnote[0] - 65;

    int Note;
    int Octave = validnote[validnote.length()-1]; //THIS IS A MATHMATICAL EQUATION TO GET THE COMPUTER TO REALISE WHAT AN OCTAVE IS USING THE MIDI NOTE CHART.

    if(validnote[0] == 'A')

    {
        MidiLetter = 9;
    }

    else if (validnote[0] == 'B')

    {
        MidiLetter = 11;
    }

    else if (validnote[0] == 'C')

    {
        MidiLetter = 12;
    }

    else if (validnote[0] == 'D')
    {
        MidiLetter = 14;
    }

    else if (validnote[0] == 'E')
    {
        MidiLetter = 16;
    }

    else if (validnote[0] == 'F')
    {
        MidiLetter = 17;
    }

    else if (validnote[0] == 'G')
    {
        MidiLetter = 19;
    }
    /////////////////////

    int midivalue = MidiLetter + (Octave * 12);
    if(validnote.length() == 3)
    {
        midivalue += 1;
    }

}

//Validation

int main()
{
string note;

int midivalue;

StartUpMenu(); //This function brings you to the start up menu

note = GetNote(); //This function tells the computer what note between A-G and  the user has given

cout << "The note you chose is: " << note << endl;

MidiStorage(note);
GetNote();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly a solution, `switch-case` would have been a better choice for you.

Comment: Can you show me an example of this?

Comment: For small set of possible cases, `switch-case` is O(1) TC, and more concise.

Comment: I think you want to return a useful value from `StartUpMenu` so you know what the choice was.

Answer (score 2):

Only in option 3, you do a break from the loop, which returns from the loop so your program continues.  Option 1 and 2 (and default) just shows the choice and stays in the loop, so a new choice is asked.  You can break when option 1 and 2 are given, but you probably want to return the option so your program can act on it.

By the way, there is a typo in your code: `else if (choice == 1;)` shouldn't contain a ';'.

Comment: I have changed the code so now when you press 2 or 3 it moves onto the GetNote() function. What shall I do to allow the command for '3' to cancel the program?

Comment: If you return the given option, you can exit when StartupMenu() returns 3

Comment: I have rectified this but now when you choose the option to continue either working with Bass or Melody, you are only allowed to input one value, what if the user wants to input more then that? How is this rectified?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling function GetNote anywhere in your code.

Comment: could you provide the full code, unless it spreads across multiple files